# Is there a block label for Delphi?

Tags: java, delphi

In Java we can make things like:

```
 String output = "";

 stop: {
 // count 10 lines

 for ( int row = 1; row <= 10; row++ ){
   // count 5 columns

   for ( int column = 1; column <= 5; column++ {
     if ( row == 5 )
       break stop;
     output += "* ";

     }

     output += "\n";
    }
   output += "\nTerminated Ok.";
  }
```

The result is a print of 10 lines, but it ends at 5:

```
 * * * * *
 * * * * *
 * * * * *
 * * * * *
 * * * * *
```

Is there a Delphi equivalent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring block level variables for branches in delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519191/declaring-block-level-variables-for-branches-in-delphi)

Comment: The code in the question doesn't need a labelled break. Perhaps you should include a more realistic example which does require a labelled break?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot No, it is not a duplication of that question because it is an entirely different question that has nothing to do with that question you mentioned, about vars declared inside a block in prism. See?

Comment: you can also use catched exceptions of custom class for short-cut exit of loops. Wether it is more or less structured, fast and consitutes creative use or abuse of language feature is a matter of dispute.

Comment: Yes, that's an exit, but we would have to use `try` on that, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi does not support an equivalent to Java's break to label.

Consider the following:

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
  for j := 1 to 10 do
    if ... then break;
```

In Delphi the `break` always breaks out of the innermost statement, the `j` for loop in the example above.

In Java you can label a block and break out of that labelled block. So in Java you could break out of the `i` for loop using a labelled break. For example:

```
outerloop: {
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
      if (...) break outerloop;
  }
}
```

Such a break is not possible in Delphi. The closest equivalent in Delphi is the dreaded `goto`, which is still [considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

var
  i, j: Integer;

label
  outerloopend;

begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      if i>5 then
        goto outerloopend;
      Write(Format('%d,%d ', [i, j]));
    end;
    Writeln;
  end;
outerloopend:
  Writeln('Edsger Dijkstra, sorry for using goto!');
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: AFAIK the example provided doesn't include a Java label, to me it looks like his just trying to exit the method.

Comment: @PeterVonča Yes the syntax in the question was wrong. I just fixed it.

Comment: Are you sure that your edit is correct? In java labels have no begin or end declaration, it would be this instead `Test : break Test` instead of using `{` and `}`. That's why my initial asumption was that he is simply looking for the Exit procedure.

Comment: @PeterVonča The code in the question is valid, is it not? Nothing wrong with writing single statements inside compound statements and including extraneous braces.